# Nested iframe css manipulation in javascript after load

Tags: javascript, iframe

My goal is to change a `fill` attribute in a `polyline` element in an `svg` sitting in a nested, same-domain, `iframe`.

When my page loads, I can see the content in the browser.  In the chrome console, from javascript, I can access the nested `iframe`, and the `div` containing the `svg`.

```
document.querySelectorAll('iframe#my-frame')[0]
.contentDocument.querySelectorAll('iframe')[0]
.contentDocument.querySelector('#mydiv')
```

but the content of that `div` is evidently not in any dom that I can interrogate.  The div is effectively empty, even though it's content is rendered in the browser.

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

When I right-click > 'Inspect' the nested iframe, the devtools redirect to the `body` element of the `iframe#document`. I am now able to interrogate the div, and manipulate the svg elements' attributes.  At this point I can no longer interrogate the parent page, because the `window` object is now the nested `iframe` itself--this is not unexpected.

But I can't reset `window` programmatically, I don't think, i.e., this doesn't work:

```
window = document.querySelectorAll('iframe#my-frame')[0].contentDocument.querySelectorAll('iframe')[0].contentWindow
```

Is there a way to programmatically change focus or `window` of the javascript running in the browser--what I assume is forcing the iframe content into the dom in order to manipulate a css attribute after page load?  Remember this is not an iframe domain issue.

Answer (score 0):

### You can't access the iframe's content instantly

You need something like a `load` eventListener to wait until the `<iframe>` content is fully loaded.

```
const myFrame = document.querySelector("#my-frame");

myFrame.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
  // content loaded - query and manipulate elements
  let doc = myFrame.contentDocument;
  let iframeSvg = doc.querySelector("svg");
  let svgEl = iframeSvg.querySelector("rect");
  svgEl.style.fill = "green";
});
```